# CSS Intelligent Merger

Tags: css, tools

I am looking for a tool very similar to http://www.tothepc.com/archives/combine-merge-multiple-css-files/

However, given this example:

test1.css:

```
#admin {
    background: #c9d2dc;
    border-color: #ccc
}
```

test2.css:

```
#admin {
    background: #222;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
    border-left: 1px solid #444;
    padding: 2px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 120px;
    z-index: 2
}
```

It will only allow you to select one or the other. I want to merge them, making it:

```
#admin {
    background: #c9d2dc;
    border-color: #ccc
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
    border-left: 1px solid #444;
    padding: 2px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 120px;
    z-index: 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The merger tool should give options for you when it spots the same id's/classes on different css files, but in this case it wouldn't allow you to merge them together. In example 1 you have the id "admin", with background set to #222. In example 2 the same id has a background designated as #c952dc. The merger can't put multiple attributes together, your css file wouldn't be valid. Each class/id, regardless of what file they exist on, should only have 1 instance of any particular attribute.

Comment: Correct, the tool gives you priority which file to use if you come up with matching attributes. Test1.css would have the priority

Answer (score 0):

Edit: My original comment was that this is not an impossible task. but actually this is wrong: because a single element can be referred to in multiple ways, in the general case one can do no better than to concatenate the files. Consider...

```
<div id="one" class="two">Some text</div>
```

with CSS

```
#one {color: red; font-weight: 900;}
.two {color: blue;)

.two {font-weight: 500;}
#one {color: green}
```

This should end up with Green text, weight 500. If you put a merged `.two` first, you get Green 900, if you put the merged `#one` first, you get Blue 500. Neither is right, and because you don't know that the two selectors refer to the same element, you can't infer the correct answer.